# Словарь трудностей русского языка

Tags: нормы-языка

Словарь трудностей Русского языка(Д.Э.Розенталь, М.А.Теленкова.) Виды норм представленных в словаре?

Answer (score 3):

А сами посмотреть не желаете? Есть онлайн -словарь.

•орфоэпические (трудности ударения)

•морфологические (вариантность образования отдельных форм типа слесари-слесаря)

•лексические нормы (словоупотребление типа надевать-одевать)

•словообразовательные(образование слов-названий народов, пары глаголов на - изовать - изировать)

•синтаксические (нормы согласования и управления, синонимия предлогов)

•орфографические нормы

•пунктуационные (запятая перед КАК, обособление оборотов с предлогами, вводные слова)

•общие и частные нормы литературной речи (стилистика, даются стилистич. пометы.)